# Stochastically converging Bernoulli-related sequence

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

$X_1, X_2, .. ,X_n$ are independent Bernoulli random variables $X_i$ ~ BIN(1,$p_i$).

Let $Y_n$ = $\sum_{i=0}^n(X_i-p_i)/n$.

The problem is to show that the sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots , Y_n$ converges stochastically to $c=0$ as $n \to \infty$ .

A hint is to use the Chebychev inequality: $P[|X-μ|>kσ] < 1/k^2$. In this case we could use $P[|X_i-p_i|\gt kp(1-p)] \lt k^{-2}$ for any $k\gt 0$.

What I tried so far was $P[Y<y] = P[\sum_{i=0}^n((X_i-p_i)/n)<y] = P[\sum_{i=0}^n(X_i-p_i)<y\cdot n] = P[n(X_i-p_i)<y\cdot n] = P[X_i-p_i<y] = P[X_i<y+p_i] = 1 - y - p_i$ 
but I feel like this is not the correct way to tackle this problem.

Comment: some stuff of your question is missing...

Comment: Your attempt is not complete. Also please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write all equations.

Comment: I tried to use the MathJax for the equations hope it looks better now.

Comment: There are many forms of stochastic convergence such as convergence in probability, distribution, almost sure etc. I assume you're talking about showing convergence in probability since the Chebyshev inequality is involved? Furthermore, what do you mean with c = 0, like a degenerate distribution in $0$?

Comment: Yes a degenerate distribution in 0, I assume it is convergence in distribution as I have not learned about the others yet.

Answer (score 2):

For all $i$, we have
$$\mathsf{Var}(X_i-p_i)=p_i(1-p_i)\leqslant \frac14. $$
It follows that
$$\mathsf{Var}\left(\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-p_i) \right)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf{Var}(X_i-p_i)\leqslant\frac1{n^2}\left(\frac n4\right)=\frac1{4n}, $$
and so by Chebyshev's inequality, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have
$$\mathbb P\left(\left|\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-p_i)\right|>\varepsilon \right)\leqslant\frac1{4n\varepsilon^2}, $$ so that $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-p_i)$ converges to $0$ in probability.